# White space scrollview Android (content size of scrollview)

Tags: android

I'm struggling with the content size of a scrollview in Android Studio.

I've made a simple scrollview with some images in it and textviews.

Everything works perfectly, but I'm struggling with one thing: The content size of the scrollview (like on iOS). I can't get the content size of the scrollview under control.. 
Now I have a white space at the end of the scrollview, but I don't want the white space to be the end of my scrollview (I think this is because the content size of my scrollview is too high, but I don't know how to control this). I want an image to be the end of the scrollview.

Here is my .xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"



        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="285dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="De schoen heeft u als bescherming van uw voet:"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:background="@drawable/inhousebtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="- Dus ook in huis, schoen aan!"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:background="@drawable/nietblotevoet"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="- Nooit op blote voeten lopen"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:background="@drawable/nietsokken"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="- Nooit op sokken lopen"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:background="@drawable/noslippers"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="- Geen slippers/sandalen"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:background="@drawable/zittenddouchen"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="- Zittend douchen"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/underthingbescherming"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Unfortunately I don't have the reputation to post images (If I had, this would be clearer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"



    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
```

or change it to

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
```

let me know if you still have problems after that.